# How do I make an app icon for a .sh or .py file

Tags: terminal, google-chrome-os

I am using a Chromebook with Linux turned on, and am wondering how I can add a shortcut to the app drawer that opens the terminal and runs a .py or .sh file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Gomenburu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a desktop file under /usr/share/applications.

For example:

```
$ ls -l /home/norioy01/hoge.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 norioy01 norioy01 28 Sep 27 09:04 /home/norioy01/hoge.sh
$ 
$ cat /home/norioy01/hoge.sh
#!/bin/bash

touch hoge.txt
$ 
$ ls -l /usr/share/applications/hoge.desktop 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 158 Sep 27 09:14 /usr/share/applications/hoge.desktop
$ 
$ cat /usr/share/applications/hoge.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=hoge
Exec=/home/norioy01/hoge.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
$
```

[image]